# Facebook open graph post link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Question:
Is there a way of configuring open graph to use the one-to-one story type title  with object link in the headline of the post instead of the one-to-one without title and link?

Example:
I'm posting 'John ate at Paul's Diner on ChilledOut' as a custom og story with a photo. When I post the story to my Facebook newsfeed it shows the title as 'John ate at a restaurant on ChilledOut' with no link to the restaurant object OG:url. However, when I click the photo in the story it takes me to the standard Facebook photo album page and in the top right hand corner is the correct story headline  of 'John ate at Paul's Diner on ChilledOut' with the OG:url link included to Paul's Diner.  How do I get the post headline title to equal the photo album page title and include the object name and link?

Comment: I don't think you can choose between '<actor> <actioned> <object instance>' and '<actor> <action> an <object type>' stories - i think they're shown in different places